# Did Aphex Twin ever used samples from someone else's tracks?

Tags: recording, sample

Did Aphex Twin used samples in his tracks and is his music 100% his own creation?

Comment: Aphex Twin has had a musical career since at least 1992. Suggest you check out some sources like [Discogs](https://www.discogs.com/artist/45-Aphex-Twin) or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphex_Twin) to find out more about him.

Answer (score 2):

Using WhoSampled.com, you can find some of the songs that [Aphex Twin has sampled](http://www.whosampled.com/Aphex-Twin/samples/). It turns out that he has sampled over 75 songs, including (among many other songs of varying popularity):

- "[Apache](http://www.whosampled.com/sample/76292/Aphex-Twin-Heliosphan-Incredible-Bongo-Band-Apache/)" by the Incredible Bongo Band
- "[When the Levee Breaks](http://www.whosampled.com/sample/50826/Aphex-Twin-Taking-Control-Led-Zeppelin-When-the-Levee-Breaks/)" by Led Zeppelin
- "[Soul Pride](http://www.whosampled.com/sample/59366/Aphex-Twin-GirlBoy-Song-James-Brown-Soul-Pride/)" by James Brown
- "[Uranium](http://www.whosampled.com/sample/332880/Aphex-Twin-Renalgade-Sonar-Kraftwerk-Uranium/)" by Kraftwerk
- "[Big Yellow Taxi](http://www.whosampled.com/sample/329283/Aphex-Twin-Parking-Lot-Joni-Mitchell-Big-Yellow-Taxi/)" by Joni Mitchell
- "[The Great Gig in the Sky](http://www.whosampled.com/sample/329285/Aphex-Twin-20-Pink-Floyd-Pink-Floyd-The-Great-Gig-in-the-Sky/)" by Pink Floyd
- "[Funky Drummer](http://www.whosampled.com/sample/375982/Aphex-Twin-droneBReak-James-Brown-Funky-Drummer/)" by James Brown ([who hasn't?](http://www.whosampled.com/James-Brown/Funky-Drummer/sampled/))
- "[Run's House](http://www.whosampled.com/sample/329284/Aphex-Twin-20-Pink-Floyd-Run-DMC-Run%27s-House/)" by Run-DMC

It seems like he has been sampling since the beginning of his career; according to WhoSampled, the [oldest song he uses sample on](http://www.whosampled.com/Aphex-Twin/samples/?ob=0) is from 1992, and the [most recent](http://www.whosampled.com/Aphex-Twin/samples/?ob=1) is from 2015.